# my thumbnails are of different size so they are not aligning properly in grid layout ,how to align them

Tags: html

**Previous problem was fixed but there is a new problem slider not working.**
I tried searching on web but found nothing .

my website link is https://testslidertk.blogspot.in/

Slider Not working.
Link of theme code={https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Pa6kznMKqZM1ZGX21ObHRra0E}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great to have the code, not just images. But even by the images it can be seen that the problem could be in the height of the images. Fix the height of the containers (set it on some fixed amount) and set image style to max-height:100%; and max-width:100%;

I think that should do the trick. If not please add html of the grid for a correct answer.

Comment: but a new problem slider not working https://testslidertk.blogspot.in/ theme code file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Pa6kznMKqZM1ZGX21ObHRra0E

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Card A1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Card A2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Card B1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Card C1
    </div>
</div>
```